# Combine subplots in Julia

Tags: julia

In Julia I know one way of combining subplots as the this:

```
p1=plot(...)
p2=plot(...)
p3=plot(...)

plot(p1, p2, p3, layout(3,1))
```

However, suppose that I don't know beforehand the number of subplots, like when I generate the subplots based of some parameters passed to a function, then how would I accomplish the same thing?

What I tried was that I made an array to contain all the subplots

```
Plot_array=[p1, p2, p3]
```

(again, the number of elements of Plot_array can be changed based on what passed to a function)

and then

```
plot(Plot_array, layout=(...))
```

However, this did not work. Does anyone know any better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
plot(Plot_array..., layout=(length(Plot_array), 1))
```

Three dots is so called "splat" operator: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#Varargs-Functions

Comment: `plot(Plot_array...)` without specifying the layout also works!